# Python For-Loop, range() with conditions

Tags: python, for-loop

My code as follows:

```
`x = input("Please enter the value of x: ")
y = input("Please enter the value of y: ")
sum = 0

for num in range(x, y+1):
    islessthanorzero = int(x) <= 0 or int(y) <= 0
    isgreaterthanx = int(x) > int(y)
    if x.isnumeric() and y.isnumeric():
        if islessthanorzero:
            print('not greater than zero')
            exit()    
        if isgreaterthanx: 
            print('not greater than y')
            exit()
        else: 
            print ('not numeric')
            exit()
    else:
        sum += num
    
print(f"The sum of numbers between {x} and {y} is {sum}")  
`
```

Requirement: users to input 2 values. sum of all numbers from x to y
Conditions:

1. x and y are numeric
2. x and y are higher than zero
3. y must be greater than
4. Use a for loop to calculate the sum of numbers from x to y

**The program will have to make sure all the conditions met before adding the sum of all numbers from x to y, else terminates the program.**

The logic for if-else works but I'm not able to implement into the for loop.

Comment: Since you have just x and y as inputs, the only thing you need to do is make the check at the beginning and if all checks pass go into the loop. No need to do the check inside of the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if-else conditions were wrong placed:

```
x = input("Please enter the value of x: ")
y = input("Please enter the value of y: ")
s = 0

if x.isnumeric() and y.isnumeric():
    if int(x) <= 0 or int(y) <= 0:
        print('not greater than zero')  
    if int(x) > int(y): 
        print('not greater than y')
        exit()
    else: 
        s += sum(list(range(int(x), int(y))))
else:
    print ('not numeric')
    exit()
    
print(f"The sum of numbers between {x} and {y} is {s}")
```

Comment: Hi, apologies as I have miss out one more condition which is to use for loop to calculate the sum of numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The input gives a `string` which you need to convert it to a `integer` before using them in a mathematical expression.

So I'd suggest you to cast the values as `integers`:

`x = int(input("Please enter the value of x: "))`

`y = int(input("Please enter the value of y: "))`

Comment: But after that, you need to compare if the variables are numeric, as String, so you can't convert them to integers at the start.

Comment: @Cardstdani well the point is, if you **can** turn them into integers, you don't need to check if they are numeric or not.